# My/The IELTS test?

Tags: grammar, definite-article

"I feel like I should've started (**my**) GMAT earlier. That way I would've been prepared for **the/my** test by now."

1. I know we usually say 'I'm taking my IELTS test tomorrow.' I'm just now sure whether 'my' is necessary before GMAT here.
2. Do we say 'the test' or 'my test?' I think both of them are correct even though 'the' sounds better to me.

Answer (score 1):

“the test” refers to the test generally, unless context makes it more specific:

- I heard the test is difficult.
- I am studying for the test.
- I will take the test next week.

“my test” refers to the specific test you took, are taking or will take:

- My test is next week.
- I think I did well on my test.

Comment: Does this mean that I should say 'my' before both 'GMAT' and 'test' here? Or does it sound better this way- "I feel like I should've started MY GMAT earlier. That way I would've been prepared for THE test by now."

Comment: @Ashraf When both “my” and “the” are allowed, I would prefer “my”, but that’s just a preference. Your version makes perfect sense.